# AWS Glue - CRON Scheduled Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, crontrigger

I have been trying to find a Cron expression to use in my AWS Glue Job. I tried many examples and I'm still not sure if this is possible or NOT, since this is the first time I'm adding time schedule to a Glue Job, in a Cloud Formation template.

We are trying to schedule the Glue Job to run in the 5th or 6th business day of each month at 10:15AM.

I tried some ideas, but none gave consistent results and many cron validators show them as incorrect.
Tried:

- 0 0 ? * 3#3 *
- 0 0 3-7 * ? *

**Examples of what I'm trying to achieve:**

**5th Business day of the Month:**

- If the Job ran in January 2023 it should run on January 6th.
- If the Job ran in December 2022 it should run on December 7th.
- If the Job is schedule for ran in July 2023 it should run on July 7th.

**6th Business day of the Month:**

- If the Job ran in January 2023 it should run on January 9th.
- If the Job ran in December 2022 it should run on December 8th.
- If the Job is schedule for ran in July 2023 it should run on July 10th.

Remember that is to be used in the Cloud Formation AWS Glue Template.

Comment: Please provide CloudFormation template demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I believe that the option will be a lambda that runs everyday and the code inside the lambda will check if it's the 6th business day of the month, if not it stops, if true it will trigger the Glue Job. I'm almost sure that with Cron I cannot have the right dates, consistently.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS (atleast), you can not set a cron expression to match "business/working" days. For cron expression there are no "business" days but only calender days.

As you mentioned, you can set a Lambda function to check if the day is a working day and then trigger the Gluen job.

Answer (score 0):

Cron doesn't support this.

The simplest solution would be to use the cron schedule to cover the possible days e.g `15 10 5-10 * 1-5` and then have Python code at the start of the Glue job that continues on or exits based on your specific business day logic.